# Java - IDX files: how to read them?

Tags: java, image-processing

During machine learning course, the professor asks us to implement, using SVM, a classifier for handwritten digits. He gave us this [dataset](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/), that contains also a train set to test the classifier.

I tried to write a java class for reading the dataset and converting it into a data structure (an HashMap, for example), but I encountered a lot of difficulties while I read the files. On the dataset's website, there is the structure of this IDX file:

The basic format is:

```
magic number 
size in dimension 0 
size in dimension 1 
size in dimension 2 
..... 
size in dimension N 
data
```

The magic number is an integer (MSB first). The first 2 bytes are always 0.

The third byte codes the type of the data:

```
0x08: unsigned byte 
0x09: signed byte 
0x0B: short (2 bytes) 
0x0C: int (4 bytes) 
0x0D: float (4 bytes) 
0x0E: double (8 bytes)
```

The 4-th byte codes the number of dimensions of the vector/matrix: 1 for vectors, 2 for matrices....

The sizes in each dimension are 4-byte integers (MSB first, high endian, like in most non-Intel processors).

The data is stored like in a C array, i.e. the index in the last dimension changes the fastest.

So I started with the file t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte:

```
[offset] [type]          [value]          [description] 
0000     32 bit integer  0x00000801(2049) magic number (MSB first) 
0004     32 bit integer  10000            number of items 
0008     unsigned byte   ??               label 
0009     unsigned byte   ??               label 
........ 
xxxx     unsigned byte   ??               label
```

This is its structure, so I wrote a java class that should read the file and compute the magic number and the number of items. This is the class:

```
public class ReadTest {

static String testLabel = "t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    byte[] bytes = null;
    byte[] fileName = testLabel.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    try {bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(testLabel));}
    catch (IOException e) {System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());}

    if(bytes != null) {

        List<Byte> listBytes = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Byte> listName = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=0; i<bytes.length; i++) listBytes.add(bytes[i]);
        for(int i=0; i<fileName.length; i++) listName.add(fileName[i]);

        System.out.println("I read " + listBytes.size() + " bytes!");
        System.out.println("Filename: " + listName.size() + " bytes!");

        if(listBytes.containsAll(listN)) System.out.println("Gotcha!");

        byte[] magic = {bytes[3], bytes[2], bytes[1], bytes[0]};
        byte[] items = {bytes[7], bytes[6], bytes[5], bytes[4]};

        System.out.println("[REVERSE] Magic: " + ByteBuffer.wrap(magic).getInt() + ". Items: " + ByteBuffer.wrap(items).getInt());
        System.out.println("[AFTER 32] Magic: " + ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes, 32, 4).getInt() + ". Items: " + ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes, 36, 4).getInt());
        System.out.println("[RAW] Magic: " + ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes, 0, 4).getInt() + ". Items: " + ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes, 4, 4).getInt());

        }

    }
}
```

I was expecting, as output, "Magic: 2049. Items: 10000", but it was not. At the begin I only read the first 8 bytes (the [RAW] print), then I tried to read them in reverse order (the [REVERSE] print). After that, I ran an hexdump on the file trying to understand where was the problem: if I didn't understand it wrongly, in the IDX file there is an header containing some information about the file, including the name. So, I converted the file name into a byte array and, using two List, I found out I was right (hopefully). So I tried, skipping the first 32 bytes, to compute again the two numbers but without success.

Did I make mistakes in the implementation? Are there some classes that help me to read these files correctly?

Sorry for the looong post, but I tried to explain the entire process (:

Comment: I already read and tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20383900/9011572) but it returns to me a OutOfMemoryError. I also tried to use only the part of the code that computes the numbers, but it gives to me the same result as my code

Comment: What error are you getting? I was able to run your program and I got the output that you expected. "I read 10008 bytes!
Filename: 50 bytes!
[REVERSE] Magic: 17301504. Items: 270991360
[AFTER 32] Magic: 67110660. Items: 66305
[RAW] Magic: 2049. Items: 10000"

Comment: One more thing you might want to check. The zip file "t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz" when extracted contains a file named "t10k-labels.idx1-ubyte". Your code has a different name, a dash instead of dot)  "t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte".

Comment: I don't know why but when I extracted the files their name remain like I wrote. I changed them into .id*-ubyte and all starts working! Thanks a lot, I think you saved my day (: