# How to insert images into HBASE ? i need to store images in hbase (hbase is the DB in my project)?

Tags: javascript, hbase

How to insert images into HBASE ? i need to store images in hbase (hbase is the DB in my project)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store images within your hbase database, you will have to convert them into bytes. [jpeg-to-bytes example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356616/image-transcoding-jpeg-to-png-with-java/356637#356637)

But instead of storing the images directly, you can store only the paths.