# java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: Provider could not be instantiated

Tags: java, javax.imageio, jai

I have a `.jp2` image file that I want to convert to `.jpg`.

```
    BufferedImage background = ImageIO.read(new File("images\\"
    + randNum + ".jp2"));
    ImageIO.write(background, "jpg", new File("images\\" + randNum
                + ".jpg"));
```

I have got this exception :

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.imageio.spi.ImageWriterSpi:  Provider com.github.jaiimageio.jpeg2000.impl.J2KImageWriterSpi could not be instantiated
 ...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/jaiimageio/impl/common/PackageUtil
 ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.jaiimageio.impl.common.PackageUtil
```

Comment: Did you try this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/356650/3398732 ?

Comment: I didn't get any error, your code perferctly created a jpg file. Could you please check you configurations?

Comment: @CodeWalker image transcoding is not working, same error, thank you, it is certainly a problem of configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, a conflict occured, I was using classes from different libraries, here I had both `jai_imageio` and `jai-imageio-jpeg2000`, I solved this problem by simply removing one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I run this code and it created a new jpg file. I hope it would help you.

```
package yourPackage;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ImageConverter {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int randNum = 1;
        convertImage(randNum);      

    }

    private static void convertImage(int randNum) throws IOException {
        try {
            File foundFile = new File("c:\\images\\" + randNum + ".jp2");   
            BufferedImage background = ImageIO.read(foundFile);
            ImageIO.write(background, "jpg", new File("c:\\images\\" + randNum + ".jpg"));
            System.out.println("jpg file is generated");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("No file " + randNum +".jp2 found");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error and not jpg file is created, do you think there is a conflict in the imports?

Comment: @TiyebBellal I've updated my answer. I hope that would work for you.

Comment: I have tried using your method and after debug I found that the exception occurs on this instruction: `BufferedImage background = ImageIO.read(foundFile);`

Comment: @TiyebBellal if you have a file in that specified location, then it should find the file.

Comment: I do have the jp2 file not the jpg, but as the error says :J2KImageWriterSpi could not be instantiated, I think it is about the library or access restrictions on it

Comment: Thank you for the effort, finally I removed jai-imageio-jpeg2000 library  and it worked!