# Rendering jp2(jpeg2000) to Imageview in android.

Tags: android, jpeg2000

I am getting jp2 in base64 format from server end. I am able to convert jpg to jp2 form ImageMagick library and send to server. They are able to convert it to jpg using Buffered Image and ImageIo . 
But I am not getting any idea to convert jp2 to jpg and render in Imageview.
Hoping for any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You probably solved it somehow already, but in case you're still looking for a solution, you can try the [JP2 for Android](https://github.com/gemalto/JP2ForAndroid) library. (Disclaimer: I wrote the library.) It's based on OpenJPEG, like the DimaArts' response, but it has a bit nicer Java interface.

Add the following dependency to your build.gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.gemalto.jp2:jp2-android:1.0'
```

and use the following code to decode the JP2:

```
byte[] jp2Data = ...; //get the JP2 data from somewhere
Bitmap bmp = new JP2Decoder(jp2Data).decode();
imgView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use OpenJpeg library for decode Jpeg2000. You can use compiled library https://github.com/DimaArts/OpenJpegAndroid. It contains an example of encode jpeg2000. Library supports PNG input and output formats for decoder and encoder.
Try this:

```
OpenJPEGJavaDecoder decoder = new OpenJPEGJavaDecoder();
String[] params2 = new String[4];
params2[0] = "-i";
params2[1] = mInputPath; // path to jp2
params2[2] = "-o";
params2[3] = mOutputPath // path to png
decoder.decodeJ2KtoImage(params2);
```

if you are using JNI:

```
public int decodeJ2KtoImage(String[] parameters) {
    return internalDecodeJ2KtoImage(parameters);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/39103107/2760681

```
private static void convertImage(int randNum) throws IOException {
    try {
        File foundFile = new File("c:\\images\\" + randNum + ".jp2");   
        BufferedImage background = ImageIO.read(foundFile);
        ImageIO.write(background, "jpg", new File("c:\\images\\" + randNum + ".jpg"));
        System.out.println("jpg file is generated");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println("No file " + randNum +".jp2 found");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.. But BufferedImage and ImageIO is not supported in Android SDK. So, Please let me know for any alternatives